# How to create multi level array which uses literal strings (Javascript)?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, string-literals

Thanks to @Aplet123  I can store literal strings in an array as functions. ([previous issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61238955/how-to-store-strings-in-an-array-that-include-template-literals-javascript)) This works great. But I can’t figure out how to do the same with nested arrays.
For example:

```
var nameTemp = `Placeholder`;
Title[0] = () => `what are you called?`;
Title[1] = () => `what does ${nameTemp} do?`;
Title[2] = () => `How old is ${nameTemp} ?`;

//--I get the users name from an input.text element and store in nameTemp
textbox.textContent = Title[1]();
```

This works well. It returns “what does [name entered] do?” and updates the Literal string when `Title[x]()` is called.

But I have multiple text items per page and I’d like to be able to retrieve them using something like:

```
Title[1][1] = () => `what does ${nameTemp} do?`;
```

I’ve tried various things, but they either don’t return the length of the second array, or don’t run the function:

```
var testC = [];
testC[0] = [];
testC[0][0]  = ()  => ` what does ${nameTemp} do?`;
console.log(testC[0][0]);
```

this just returns  “**()  => ` what does ${nameTemp} do?**” it doesn’t run the function.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It returns the function and you forgot to call the function using `()`

```js
var nameTemp = 'John';
var testC = [];
testC[0] = [];
testC[0][0]  = ()  => ` what does ${nameTemp} do?`;
console.log(testC[0][0]());
```

Comment: Unbelievable – that deserves the biggest face slap! I can’t believe I missed that. I’ve been staring at this for hours – talk about not seeing the wood for the tress. Thank you very much!! That’s made my life much easier!!